# 'The parameter "debug.error_handler.throw_at" must be defined' error after updating to Symfony 2.6

Tags: symfony

After updating Symfony with Composer to version 2.6 it gives this error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] The parameter "debug.error_handler.throw_at" must be defined.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

manualy clear application cache -
remove all files in /app/cache:
`rm -r app/cache/*`

and then warmup cache for needed environment like that:

`app/console cache:warmup --env=prod`

Comment: Thanks. Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: what a weird bug.. looks like it caches the config.yml then refuses to see it might have changed so doesnt renew it.

Comment: I suspect post-install or post-update scripts use stale configuration.
I did not dig further because the error no longer occurs after 2.6.?

Comment: It occurred for me when upgrading from 2.5 to 2.7.3